# org src fontify won't highlight some multiline comments

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, faces

The option `org-src-fontify-natively` doesn't care about some multi-line comments. See:
[image: org multi-line comments]

As shown in the picture above, the html comment isn't highlighted correctly. I tried hacking through the code and I see that `html-mode` seems use to the function `syntax-propertize-rules` to propertize the comment, while `c-mode` seems to use only the syntax-table. I think this is so because the syntax-table can't handle the `<!--` kind of comment.

So how can I customize `html-mode` to make the comments highlighted by `org-mode`, or customize `orb-mode` to not ignore them?